# Why is this for loop iterating only once?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I don't know why this for loop is only iterating once.
Just a note, I'm quite new to JavaScript.

```
function bubbleSort(nums) {
    bubbleSortedArray = nums;
    lenOfBSA = bubbleSortedArray.length;
    for (i = 0; i < lenOfBSA; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < lenOfBSA - i - 1; j++) {
            if (bubbleSortedArray[j] > bubbleSortedArray[j + 1]) {
                swap(bubbleSortedArray, j, j + 1);
                showSorting(bubbleSortedArray); // when i comment this out and call it elsewhere it works
            }
        }
    }
}

function showSorting(nums) {
    canvasprops = setup();
    cc = canvasprops[0];
    c = canvasprops[1];
    cc.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    cc.fillStyle = "lime";
    cc.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    console.log("updated canvas");

    var x = 0;
    cc.fillStyle = "black";
    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        cc.fillRect(x, c.height, 8, 6 * -nums[i]);
        x = x + 8;
    }
}


function setup() {
    var c = document.getElementById("sort-viewer");
    cc = c.getContext("2d");
    c.setAttribute("width", "800px");
    c.setAttribute("height", "620px");
    return [cc, c];
}

function swap(arr, a, b) {
    temp = arr[a];
    arr[a] = arr[b];
    arr[b] = temp;
    console.log("swapped");
}
```

When I comment `showSorting(bubbleSortedArray);` out from the nested for loop, and place it at the end of the for loops it works, with the for loops iterating multiple times. However, when it's in the nested for loops, there is only one iteration happening for some reason.

The point here is, I'm trying to draw to the canvas each time, to show the array being sorted (trying to create a visualisation).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do `console.log(bubbleSortedArray.length);` What number does this show?

Comment: @Will it shows 100.

Comment: You failed to declare the loop index variables, so they're **global**. (In fact it looks like *none* of your variables are correctly declared.)

Comment: i.e. `for (var i = 0;`

Comment: This has solved my error, thanks everyone! @Pointy could you post your comment as an answer, and I'd be more than willing to mark it as an answer.

Comment: By the way, outer loop should be `while (aSwapWasMade)`, this boolean should be initialized to true, then set to false immediatly at the begining of the while loop, and set back to true every time you need to swap. This will greatly improve that bbsort performance

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, the inner for loop should then be `for (let j = 0; j < lenOfBSA - 1; j++)` and **after** that loop : `lenOfBSA--`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not declaring i. It is then a global variable and used by all iterators. Your showSorting function is changing i, therefore the for loop exits.

```
for(i = 0;i < 10; i++){
   // here i is global since it is not declared and scoped to the for loop
}

for(var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
   // here i is declared and initilized, and scoped to the current function
}
// which means I can access i here:
console.log(i); // outputs 9

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   // here i is declared and initilized and scoped to the loop only. i is not accessible outside of this loop.
}
```

Change your for loops to use `let i = 0` instead of `i = 0` and it should work.

Comment: Yes! I really should have looked up the fundamentals of JavaScript before diving right in, but I couldn't stop myself. Thank you!